# Komodo Edit shortcuts on Mac?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, komodoedit

I am trying to find some shortcuts for Komo Edit on Mac. How do i set up the traditional cmd+i to invoke file/folder properties? Also, i cant seem to figure out the shortcut for "Show in Finder". Any tips about the shortcuts will be helpful. I am using v7.1 and python3.2 with OSX 10.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OSX Keybindings](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/osxkeybind.html) are documented. Use the [Key Bindings menu](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/prefs.html#Config_Key_Bindings) to redefine the defaults.